# Lost certificate of apk

Tags: android, certificate, apk

I have release e free apk in google play and now I want to release e new update of app but i have lost certificate. I remember the password that I choose but dont have .jks file. Is there any chance to find the old certificate(i have a copy of apk file)?
Thank you

Comment: Çun Tirone please check the answer you find more useful to your matters. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to get it back. If you created it using eclipse or other ide try looking in the project/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the apk, there is no way to get it back, sorry. Try to find a **.keystore** (not .jks) instead, cause this is the new format of keystore used by Android Studio (make an extensive search on your computer and drives - even mobile!). Also, search at your email account, maybe you saved some backup there. Best.

Edit: just to avoid loss of time, if you don't know, excuse me: if you make another app with the same name (com.yourname.yourpackage) - and thus with another certificate, Google Play will recognize this as a new app, not a new version of that old app.

Comment: Çun, it's everything ok? Need more help? Thanks.